# react - reference to component passed as a prompt

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I rendered EditModal component in my Test component. Iam referencing it by 'this.edit'.
I passed UserForm component as prompt to EditModal. I also tried to reference it. But 'this.form' returns undefined.

Why? Is there any way to solve this?

```
class Test extends React.Component {

   test(){
     this.form.someMethod();
   }

    render() {   
      return (
        <div>            
          <EditModal form={<UserForm ref={(form) => { this.form = form; }} />} ref={(edit) => { this.edit = edit; }}/>                        
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
export default Test;
```

//EditModal.js

```
class EditModal extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.state = { show: false};
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    handleShow(id) {
        this.setState({ show: true, currentId: id});
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton={false}>
            <Modal.Title>Uprav zaznam</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
           {this.props.form}
        </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Zatvorit</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default EditModal;
```

Comment: What are this.form and this.edit? Where are they defined. Please post the code that includes them.

Comment: They are referenced in EditModal component.

Comment: I am not familiar with it, sorry...

Comment: At what moment did you call `this.form.someMethod();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.form` will be accessible once the `UserForm` component has been mounted (presumably inside the `EditModal`) and only if the `EditModal` does not clone the form prop and overrides the `ref`.

So if `this.form` is undefined, either it has not been mounted yet, or has been unmounted (by the time test method is invoked) or the `ref` has been overriden.

Without the code for `EditModal` it is not possible for anyone to determine which of the above is the case.

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ console.log(this.form); }.bind(this), 3000);
Now it returns object in test method. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to find a better approach than to use setTimeout. You can perhaps start the operation which depends on this.editForm in the ref callback itself when you receive the component instance.